# only return unique values for search results - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to only return unique _source values in my query. Right now, the below query returns a bunch of objects with `"_source": {"serviceTitle": "Blood Count" }` I would like it to only return one.

I have a query like this:

```
{
    "_source": ["serviceTitle"],
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "blood count",
            "type": "bool_prefix", 
            "fields": [ 
                "serviceTitle",
                "serviceTitle._2gram",
                "serviceTitle._3gram"
                
            ]
        }
      }
  }
```

will return this:

```
    "took": 317,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 297,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 7.6956334,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "recommendation-charlie",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "service_14815",
                "_score": 7.6956334,
                "_source": {
                    "serviceTitle": "Blood Count"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "recommendation-charlie",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "service_17946",
                "_score": 7.6956334,
                "_source": {
                    "serviceTitle": "Blood Count"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "recommendation-charlie",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "service_1459",
                "_score": 7.551247,
                "_source": {
                    "serviceTitle": "Blood Count"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like change as little of my initial query, I know I can maybe to `aggs:` but that forces me to change other parts of my query. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the mapping of the field `serviceTitle`?

Comment: ```{"recommendation-charlie": {"mappings": { "properties": {"citations": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serviceTitle": {
                    "type": "search_as_you_type",
                    "max_shingle_size": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}``` @JoeSorocin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as straightforward as you might've hoped. The easiest way to go would be to:

1. Drop the index and adjust the mapping as follows:

```
PUT recommendation-charlie
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "citations": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "serviceTitle": {                     <---
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "as_i_type": {                    <---
            "type": "search_as_you_type",
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          },
          "keyword": {                      <---
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Reindex your docs
3. Search the `.as_i_type` field (more on multi fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers)) but aggregate on `.keyword`:

```
POST recommendation-charlie/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "serviceTitle"
  ],
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "blood count",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "serviceTitle.as_i_type",           <---
        "serviceTitle.as_i_type._2gram",
        "serviceTitle.as_i_type._3gram"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_unique_titles": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serviceTitle.keyword",
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this was very helpful! is there a way where I can order the aggregation results by score and not doc_count?

Comment: other than that, everything works as you suggested doing, so thank you!

Comment: Great! Well the basic order is either `_key` (alphabetical) or `_count`. In contrast, `_score` is not part of the `aggs` API in the sense that the aggs "have no idea" what the scores are in the `hits` part of the response. There are alternatives using single-value metric aggs as outlined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)... Would you mind elaborating on why exactly you need them sorted by score?

Comment: the idea is that this is gonna be an autocomplete feature for search inputs. So ideally the most similar would be recommended at the top, but to be honest the highest doc_count might be useful as well in terms of UX.

Comment: Oh ok. Turns out I was wrong -- the `_score` is indeed available in the aggs -- but only as a child aggregation which you can then reference in the `order` of the `terms` aggs. Updated my answer.